# Drag and drop doesn't work on PyQt6 Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, user-interface, pyqt

My code contains a QListWidget in PyQt6 where items can be reordered by drag and drop. But, from a few months ago, the drag and drop mode has been "disabled", I cannot reorder my lists anymore. The same code in other computer seems to work well.

To give a minimum example:

```py
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        list_widget = QListWidget()

        # I've tried all combinations of the following calls
        list_widget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SelectionMode.SingleSelection)
        list_widget.setDragEnabled(True)
        list_widget.viewport().setAcceptDrops(True)
        list_widget.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        list_widget.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDropMode.InternalMove)

        list_widget.addItem("Item 1")
        list_widget.addItem("Item 2")
        list_widget.addItem("Item 3")
        list_widget.addItem("Item 4")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(list_widget)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

The code above doesn't allow me to drag and drop items. I'm on Ubuntu 23.04, PyQt 6.5, Python 3.10.11 inside a Conda environment. I guess this is a OS or Qt building problem but I have no clue...

Comment: More than the OS, you should first check if the Qt versions match (see `QtCore.Q_VERSION_STR`), as it might be a regression (or a solved bug if the other computer uses a more recent version).

Comment: Both computers (the one that works and the one that doesn't) have PyQt 6.5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to GNOME and Mutter with [its own thread](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/2715). I think the best solution is to wait for a patch on Ubuntu 23.04 or downgrade Ubuntu.

One other solution is to [set Wayland as the sindow system](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop).